# Trying to test two check boxes in modal react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a modal that has two checkboxes.  One is checked and the other is not (by default).  I am trying to write a test that finds box checkboxes with their default values.

```
            <Checkbox
              float="left"
              paddingTop="20px"
              mr="10px"
              borderColor="gray.50"
            />
            <TextContainer textStyle="textSm" fontWeight="normal" pt="25px">
              Make Account Admin
            </TextContainer>


            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked={welcomeEmail}
              float="left"
              paddingTop="1%"
              paddingBottom="5%"
              mr="10px"
              borderColor="gray.50"
            />
            <TextContainer textStyle="textSm" fontWeight="normal" pt="2px">
              Send welcome emails
            </TextContainer>
```

I tried queryByRole but it found multiple checkboxes.  So I am trying to see how I can distinguish between both.  any thoughts.

```
const checkbox = screen.queryByRole('checkbox');
expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the postion of these checkboxes remains constant when this page is rendered, then you could find all of them using `getAllByRole` (this returns all checkboxes found in an array) and then assert their values e.g.

```
const checkboxes = screen.getAllByRole('checkbox');
expect(checkboxes[0]).not.toBeChecked();
expect(checkboxes[1]).toBeChecked();
```